# timestamp Laravel

Tags: laravel

```
    Schema::create('user_params', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('login');
        $table->string('versionApp');
        $table->string('platform');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

почему в бд записывается время неправильное?
работаю в Laravel;

Comment: Возможно с временной зоной проблема. Попробуй поиграться с ней

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо заменить timezone в файле конфигурации **config/app.php**

```
'timezone'        => 'UTC',
```

Но для более эффективной работы с датами советуют использовать библиотеку **Carbon**

Comment: да, нашел, разобрался, спасибо